# Is it possible to call a user-defined function without the schema name?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, schema

I'm using MS SQL 2005 and when I create a function I need to put the schema name to call it:

```
select dbo.MyFunc
```

All my tables are also in "dbo" schema and I don't need the schema name to reference it, so I'd like to know if I'm missing some configuration that could do the same to functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use a function on a Microsoft SQL Server Query without using "dbo." before the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207036/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-function-on-a-microsoft-sql-server-query-without-using)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Short answer, no it isn't.

You should consider to prefix **all** your database objects with the schema owner to avoid having sql server to "look it up".

It makes your statements more readable and gives a slight increase in performance (although you'd probably won't notice it).

Regards,
Lieven

Answer (score 9):

Unlike all the other database objects (tables, views and stored procedures), user defined functions always need the schema name when they are referenced. It's a quirk of SQL Server.

Answer (score 9):

*Scalar-valued functions must be invoked by using at least the two-part name of the function

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx

+1 Parent

Borik