# User defined function in sql not working without 'dbo.' prifix to function name

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to use a function on a Microsoft SQL Server Query without using “dbo.” before the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207036/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-function-on-a-microsoft-sql-server-query-without-using)

i have a problem with my user-defined function in SQL Server,
when i try to executes it without dbo it shows error

**'GetApplicationNumber' is not a recognized built-in function name.**

```
  SET @ApplicationNumber=dbo.GetApplicationNumber(SCOPE_IDENTITY())  --WORKING FINE

  SET @ApplicationNumber=GetApplicationNumber(SCOPE_IDENTITY()) --SHOWING ERRORS
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Use the first (schema qualified) one that works.

Answer (score 0):

UDF always need the schema name when they are referenced,
and they makes statements readable and gives a slight increase in performance too.