# Problem using a function that returns int

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's a very simple function to return student id by name.The function works but I have trouble getting use of it:

```
--function to find student id by name (works)
create function findStudent (@name nvarchar(15), @familyName nvarchar(15))
returns tinyint
as
begin
    declare @id tinyint
    select @id = (select teaID from Tea where teaFirstName = @name and teaLastName = @familyName)
    return @id
end;

--using the function (doesn't work)
declare @id tinyint
select @id = (execute findStudent 'Arash', 'Mitooie')
print @id
```

Comment: Where did you find example syntax that you `execute` a function or that you pass arguments without parens? Try `SELECT @id = dbo.findStudent(N'Arash'. N'Mitooie');`

Answer (score 1):

You have a function.  No execute is necessary.  Just plug it into a `select`:

```
declare @id tinyint;
select @id = dbo.findStudent('Arash', 'Mitooie');
print @id;
```

You can also define this as a stored procedure.  In that case, I would advise passing the `@id` in as an `OUTPUT` parameter and assigning the value in the procedure.

You should also review the differences between stored procedures and stored functions, because you seem to be confusing the two.  At the simplest, stored functions return either a single value or a result set and are intended to be used in queries.  Stored procedures cannot be used in queries (with the exception of `insert` under some special circumstances that I don't recommend using).

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I do intend to use it in queries, but unfortunately it doesn't work your way either . . . 
BTW: Are all those semicolons necessary in SQL?

Comment: @Arash No they are not strictly necessary _today_, but they may be someday, so it is just a good idea. [See this post](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons). Also re: `dbo.` prefix see [this one](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix). What does "doesn't work the way you've written it" mean?

Comment: @ArashMitooie . . . That is because functions have to include the schema name in SQL Server.

Comment: actually you *can* execute functions, and in the case of `exec` the schema is not required. I don't recommend that though. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207036/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-function-on-a-microsoft-sql-server-query-without-using/5207124#5207124

Comment: @Gordon, @Aron
Thanks guys. A `dbo.` before function name solved it.