# UNIX_TIMESTAMP in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, unix-timestamp

I need to create a function in SQL Server 2008 that will mimic mysql's `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you're not bothered about dates before 1970, or millisecond precision, just do:

```
-- SQL Server
SELECT DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01 00:00:00', DateField)
```

Almost as simple as MySQL's built-in function:

```
-- MySQL
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DateField);
```

Other languages (Oracle, PostgreSQL, etc): [How to get the current epoch time in ...](https://www.epochconverter.com/#code)

---

If you need millisecond precision (SQL Server 2016/13.x and later):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF_BIG(ms, '1970-01-01 00:00:00', DateField)
```

Comment: This works great, but wow, come on Microsoft - how hard is it to just create a proper unix timestamp function!

Answer (score 24):

Try this post:
https://web.archive.org/web/20141216081938/http://skinn3r.wordpress.com/2009/01/26/t-sql-datetime-to-unix-timestamp/

```
CREATE FUNCTION UNIX_TIMESTAMP (
@ctimestamp datetime
)
RETURNS integer
AS 
BEGIN
  /* Function body */
  declare @return integer

  SELECT @return = DATEDIFF(SECOND,{d '1970-01-01'}, @ctimestamp)

  return @return
END
```

or this post:

http://mysql.databases.aspfaq.com/how-do-i-convert-a-sql-server-datetime-value-to-a-unix-timestamp.html

code is as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DTtoUnixTS 
( 
    @dt DATETIME 
) 
RETURNS BIGINT 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @diff BIGINT 
    IF @dt >= '20380119' 
    BEGIN 
        SET @diff = CONVERT(BIGINT, DATEDIFF(S, '19700101', '20380119')) 
            + CONVERT(BIGINT, DATEDIFF(S, '20380119', @dt)) 
    END 
    ELSE 
        SET @diff = DATEDIFF(S, '19700101', @dt) 
    RETURN @diff 
END
```

Sample usage:

```
SELECT dbo.DTtoUnixTS(GETDATE()) 
-- or 
SELECT UnixTimestamp = dbo.DTtoUnixTS(someColumn) 
    FROM someTable
```

Comment: i've tried the first one. executing "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(GETDATE());"  returns "'UNIX_TIMESTAMP' is not a recognized built-in function name.".    trying to run (again) the setup query returns "Msg 2714, Level 16, State 3, Procedure UNIX_TIMESTAMP, Line 12
There is already an object named 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP' in the database."

Comment: Did you try SELECT dbo.UNIX_TIMESTAMP(GETDATE()); ?

Comment: the second worked fine. but trying to name it just as 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP' produced same results as described before.  isn't there a way to make it named 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP' ? i'm trying to avoid modifying pretty much code, that needs to work with mysql AND mssql

Comment: You need to log into mssql with user with default schema dbo.That's all.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190387.aspx .If you have SQL Server management studio and 'sa' access you can setup it in 10 seconds.

Comment: " dbo.UNIX_TIMESTAMP(GETDATE()); "  works, thanks. but it would still require modifying much code to switch between the functions according to the database being used

Comment: Perhaps you can give ALTER example how to change the default schema for user? I spent much more then 10 seconds (about 10 minutes :) ) and still can't get it right. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, finally found and changed it - but it still doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Start SQL Server management studio.Go to Security -> Logins and find login which you are using.Set default database "master".Go to user mapping.There should be row for your database, user and default schema set to "dba".Is'n it?

Comment: It seems impossible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502949/is-it-possible-to-call-a-user-defined-function-without-the-schema-name

Comment: Be aware that unix timestamps count the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 at 00:00:00 UTC! That means, that if your SQL server is running local time, you may not get the correct unix timestamp using this approach.

Comment: GETUTCDATE() will return a UTC `datetime` with millisecond precision, supported since at least MSSQL 2012. If you need sub-millisecond precision, SYSUTCDATETIME() returns a UTC `datetime2(7)` timestamp.

Comment: The answer should be edited. `GETDATE()` is simply wrong, only `GetUTCDate()` is correct in regards to Unix timestamps!

Answer (score 8):

Sql Server 2016 and later have a DATEDIFF_BIG function that can be used to get the milliseconds.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF_BIG(millisecond, '1970-01-01 00:00:00', GETUTCDATE())
```

Create a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
    RETURNS BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN DATEDIFF_BIG(millisecond, '1970-01-01 00:00:00', GETUTCDATE())
END
```

And execute it

```
SELECT dbo.UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Using `GETDATE()` is wrong, `GetUTCDate()` is correct

Comment: But does this work for all timezones? 

Will SELECT dbo.UNIX_TIMESTAMP() give me the time in my local timezone? Or will it give me the UTC time?

Answer (score 3):

For timestamp with milliseconds result I found this solution from here https://gist.github.com/rsim/d11652a8336137832df9:

```
SELECT (cast(DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01', GETUTCDATE()) as bigint)*1000+datepart(ms,getutcdate()))
```

Answer from @Rafe didn't work for me correctly (MSSQL 20212) - I got 9 seconds of difference.

Answer (score 2):

I often need a unix timestamp with millisecond precision. The following will give you the current unixtime as `FLOAT`; wrap per answers above to get a function or convert arbitrary strings.

The `DATETIME` datatype on SQL Server is only good to 3 msec, so I have different examples for SQL Server 2005 and 2008+. Sadly there is no `DATEDIFF2` function, so various tricks are required to avoid `DATEDIFF` integer overflow even with 2008+. (I can't believe they introduced a whole new `DATETIME2` datatype without fixing this.)

For regular old `DATETIME`, I just use a sleazy cast to float, which returns (floating point) number of days since 1900.

Now I know at this point, you are thinking WHAT ABOUT LEAP SECONDS?!?! Neither Windows time nor unixtime really believe in leap seconds: a day is always 1.00000 days long to SQL Server, and 86400 seconds long to unixtime. [This wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#Leap_seconds) discusses how unixtime behaves during leap seconds; Windows I believe just views leap seconds like any other clock error. So while there is no systematic drift between the two systems when a leap second occurs, they will not agree at the sub-second level during and immediately following a leap second.

```
-- the right way, for sql server 2008 and greater
declare @unixepoch2 datetime2;
declare @now2 Datetime2;
declare @days int;
declare @millisec int;
declare @today datetime2;
set @unixepoch2 = '1970-01-01 00:00:00.0000';
set @now2 = SYSUTCDATETIME();
set @days = DATEDIFF(DAY,@unixepoch2,@now2);
set @today = DATEADD(DAY,@days,@unixepoch2);
set @millisec = DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,@today,@now2);
select (CAST (@days as float) * 86400) + (CAST(@millisec as float ) / 1000)
  as UnixTimeFloatSQL2008

-- Note datetimes are only accurate to 3 msec, so this is less precise 
-- than above, but works on any edition of SQL Server.
declare @sqlepoch datetime;
declare @unixepoch datetime;
declare @offset float;
set @sqlepoch = '1900-01-01 00:00:00';
set @unixepoch = '1970-01-01 00:00:00';
set @offset = cast (@sqlepoch as float) - cast (@unixepoch as float);
select ( cast (GetUTCDate() as float) + @offset) * 86400 
  as UnixTimeFloatSQL2005;

-- Future developers may hate you, but you can put the offset in
-- as a const because it isn't going to change. 
declare @sql_to_unix_epoch_in_days float;
set @sql_to_unix_epoch_in_days = 25567.0;
select ( cast (GetUTCDate() as float) - @sql_to_unix_epoch_in_days) * 86400.0 
  as UnixTimeFloatSQL2005MagicNumber;
```

FLOATs actually default to 8-byte doubles on SQL Server, and therefore superior to 32-bit `INT` for many use cases. (For example, they won't roll over in 2038.)

Comment: For "-- the right way, for sql server 2008 and greater" I had to multiply the result by 1000 to remove the decimal points it was creating. Get the millisecond epoc after that. Works like a charm. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Necromancing.
The ODBC-way:

```
DECLARE @unix_timestamp varchar(20)
-- SET @unix_timestamp = CAST({fn timestampdiff(SQL_TSI_SECOND,{d '1970-01-01'}, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)} AS varchar(20)) 

IF CURRENT_TIMESTAMP >= '20380119' 
BEGIN 
    SET @unix_timestamp = CAST
    (
        CAST
        (
            {fn timestampdiff(SQL_TSI_SECOND,{d '1970-01-01'}, {d '2038-01-19'})} 
            AS bigint
        )  
        + 
        CAST
        (
            {fn timestampdiff(SQL_TSI_SECOND,{d '2038-01-19'}, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)}
            AS bigint
        ) 
    AS varchar(20)
    ) 
END 
ELSE 
    SET @unix_timestamp = CAST({fn timestampdiff(SQL_TSI_SECOND,{d '1970-01-01'}, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)} AS varchar(20))

PRINT @unix_timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a single-line solution without declaring any function or variable:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(GETUTCDATE()-'1970-01-01' AS decimal(38,10))*86400000.5 as bigint)
```

Comment: But that only accommodates the UTC time zone.

Comment: that is what saved me and the OP asked the same. if you want native timezone replace GETUTCDATE with GETDATE. however you will mess up the unix timestamp using it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to deal with previous versions of SQL Server (<2016) and you only care for positive timestamps, I post here the solution I found for very distant dates (so you can get rid of the IF from @rkosegi's answer.

What I did was first calculating the difference in days and then adding the difference in seconds left.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[UNIX_TIMESTAMP]
( 
    @inputDate DATETIME 
)
RETURNS BIGINT 
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @differenceInDays BIGINT, @result BIGINT;
    SET @differenceInDays = DATEDIFF(DAY, '19700101', @inputDate)
    IF @differenceInDays >= 0
        SET @result = (@differenceInDays * 86400) + DATEDIFF(SECOND, DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @inputDate)), @inputDate)
    ELSE
        SET @result = 0
    RETURN @result
END
```

Answer (score 0):

When called to Scalar-valued Functions can use following syntax

Function Script :

```
USE [Database]
GO

/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[UNIX_TIMESTAMP]  ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[UNIX_TIMESTAMP] (
@ctimestamp datetime
)
RETURNS integer
AS
BEGIN
  /* Function body */
  declare @return integer

  SELECT @return = DATEDIFF(SECOND,{d '1970-01-01'}, @ctimestamp)

  return @return
END 
GO
```

Call Function :

```
SELECT dbo.UNIX_TIMESTAMP(GETDATE());
```

Comment: `GETDATE()` is wrong, only `GetUTCDate()` is correct in regards to Unix timestamps!