# Interpreting Dates from SQL Query results

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I am querying a particular table from a SQL DB. The table contains few  columns that are related to date. 
When I use a Select query on the table, the results are shown like below where some Alias/random numbers are shown instead of the actual dates ( F_CRTM and F_EDTM are meant to be columns that show the actual dates ).
Can someone help me on how to get the actual value that I am looking for( in this case date). I tried to see the table structure, but unfortuately I dont have access to that. So, I dont have any idea whether this is because of the way the table itself is structured or if there is any I can do about it.

The results that I get are shown below:

```
 F_SGRP          F_CRTM          F_EDTM
    1452759805  1452759805       1452759805
    1452759946  1452759946       1452759946
    1452759975  1452759975       1452759975
    1452760148  1452760148       1452761593
    1452760411  1452760411       1452761580
    1452761896  1452761896       1452761896
    1452761903  1452761903       1452761903
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (When it comes do date/time, those products are not compatible.)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837225/unix-timestamp-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use date arithmetic:

```
select date_add(second, F_SGRP, '1970-01-01') as F_SGRP_DATETIME,
       date_add(second, F_CRTM, '1970-01-01') as F_CRTM_DATETIME,
       date_add(second, F_EDTM, '1970-01-01') as F_EDTM_DATETIME
from t;
```

These look like Unix style datetime formats, so the value is the number of seconds starting on 1970-01-01.

Answer (score -1):

OK,just use `from_unixtime` to implement your requirement, the examples as below:

```
mysql> select from_unixtime(1452759805) as time;
+---------------------+
| time                |
+---------------------+
| 2016-01-14 16:23:25 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select date(from_unixtime(1452759805)) as date;
+------------+
| date       |
+------------+
| 2016-01-14 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So your complete SQL maybe:

```
select
    date(from_unixtime(F_SGRP)) as F_SGRP_DATE,
    date(from_unixtime(F_CRTM)) as F_CRTM_DATE,
    date(from_unixtime(F_EDTM)) as F_EDTM_DATE
from
    your_table
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. But this looks like a function that wont work in SQL 2008 (as the DB I am working on is 2008 ) because I am getting an error that 'from_unixtime' is not a recognized built-in function name. Is there a way to achieve this in SQL 2008?

Comment: @Krishna OK, you write `mysql` tag in your question, so I thought you just use a mysql database now. :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119386/how-to-convert-sql-servers-timestamp-column-to-datetime-format/8119407   this maybe your answer in a `sql server` way. @Krishna

Comment: Apologies for that tag :( Thank you one again. Let me have a look at it and try :)