# How to convert number to datetime in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, type-conversion

I have a number like this **1628864262422** and I wish to to convert it to **datetime** in SQL Server. How do I do this?

Thank you

Comment: And explain how that number should be translated into a date i.e. what should the result of that value be? And note, a datetime datatype does not have a display format (hence why I removed it from your question).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UNIX\_TIMESTAMP in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837225/unix-timestamp-in-sql-server)

Comment: And what datetime would that be?  There are literally dozens  of different used "epochs" for numerical date/time values.  An example of some of them:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing).

Answer (score 4):

If you don't care about the MS, you can try

```
Select dateadd(SECOND,1628864262422/1000,'1970-01-01')
```

**Results**

```
2021-08-13 14:17:42.000
```

Comment: That's gorgeous man, You're a life saver. Can you briefly explain to me like why do we add '1970-01-01' at the end ? i mean how do you know why we have to add that specific date?

Comment: @NamNguyen I just assumed a UNIX time stamp take a peek at https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php