# Incorrect syntax near '@StartDate'. Statement(s) could not be prepared

Tags: sql-server, stimulsoft

I try to get pdf report by stimulsoft but get this error.

> Incorrect syntax near '@StartDate'. Statement(s) could not be prepared

I test my stored procedure and table function in sqlserver and worked currently.but when I try to run VeiwData in dictionary window get me this error.
Query text in stimulsoft :

```
execute ProceGetCharterReportPdf (@StartDate,@endDate,@top,@AgencyName)
```

Type of   `@StartDate,@endDate,@AgencyName` is nvarchar in report file and stored procedure and function .Type of  `@top` is `int`.

Comment: Remove the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to sound daft, but try adding your schema name if you're calling a function;

```
execute dbo.ProceGetCharterReportPdf(@StartDate,@endDate,@top,@AgencyName)
```

You have to use the schema name when calling a function I believe, some further reading below;

[Is it possible to call a user-defined function without the schema name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502949/is-it-possible-to-call-a-user-defined-function-without-the-schema-name)

[Is there a way to use a function on a Microsoft SQL Server Query without using "dbo." before the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207036/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-function-on-a-microsoft-sql-server-query-without-using)

Comment: According to the [grammar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx), parentheses are required when executing a string or a variable, and not allowed when calling a stored object.